# xlsxwriter overwrites the previous sheet

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to put a pivot table on one column and detail on the second sheet. But the detail sheet is being overwritten by xlsxwriter.

```
pivot = pd.pivot_table(df2, index=['Customer_Name'], values=['Billed_Net_Value', 'Sales_Order_Net_Value', 'Open_Amount'], aggfunc=np.sum)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('SAP.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
pivot.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Pivot')
writer.save()

filename = 'SAP.xlsx'
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(filename)
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Detail')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example the `Workbook()` constructor creates a new file which overwrites the file created in Pandas.

If you want to add other dataframes to the workbook you can call `to_excel()` with other worksheet names, like this:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('SAP.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

pivot.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Pivot')
df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet2')
writer.save()
```

If you want to add a worksheet using the XlsxWriter apis you can do it as follows:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('SAP.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

pivot.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Pivot')

workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Detail')
writer.save()
```

See also [Working with Pandas](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html) in the XlsxWriter docs.

Comment: I cannot get this to work without deleting all other sheets. Rough outline: `writer=pd.ExcelWriter('xlsxwriter')` `df.to_excel(writer, startrow=1, sheet_name="name")` `workbook = writer.book` `worksheet = workbook.get_worksheet_by_name("name") or workbook.add_sheet("name")` `column_settings=...` `worksheet.add_table(...)` `worksheet-set_column(...)` `writer.close()` if I open the file in Excel and add a new sheet then re-run the above, it still wipes the added sheet. I need to keep it as I am adding a pivottable and chart, the creation of which is not supported xlsxwriter

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do this simply by postponing the `.save()` call:

```
pivot = pd.pivot_table(df2, index=['Customer_Name'], values=['Billed_Net_Value', 'Sales_Order_Net_Value', 'Open_Amount'], aggfunc=np.sum)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('SAP.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
pivot.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Pivot')
df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Detail')
writer.save()
```